# Running HF Model locally on GPY (MacBook PRO M3)

Tags: macos, gpu, huggingface

In my code (Python), I'm using a locally downloaded HF model as part of the project's general logic. I'm wondering if there's a way to accelerate the computations by utilizing the standard GPU on a Mac. When I run the script and check the Activity Monitor, I notice that the GPU usage is at 0%, indicating that all computations are currently being processed on the CPU.

I've tried with .to('cuda'), but clearly it doesn't work beacause there is no NVIDIA gpu.